# Jssor Slider download broken

Tags: download, slider, jssor

I found your slider a couple months back. It worked brilliantly and I'm so happy you are sharing this!

I have another project that I wanted to use the slider for, but when I tried downloading the files it extracts the folder as a .CPGZ... which I try to extract but it goes back to a .zip. Making an infinite loop of extracting, but not really. I also tried downloading from a different browser which didn't work. Could the download file be corrupt? Here is a link to the one that I am talking about:
http://www.jssor.com/demos/full-width-slider.slider.

Thanks in advance!
Valerie

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are doing it right?

there is button to 'generate zip' and then 'download zip'

I tried and it works just fine

http://www.jssor.com/demos/full-width-slider.slider

Comment: I just tried it again to check. It still is doing the infinite extraction loop. Also the generate code and save as buttons are greyed out. Not sure if they are supposed to be?

What computer/browser are you downloading from? I'm on a mac with google chrome.